# Best way to transfer data from AWS DynamoDB to individual files in an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

We are storing the outgoing mails of our platform in a RDS MySQL database (id, timestamp, mailTo, mailFrom, ...). The mailbody itself is not stored in the MySQL table but is stored as an individual file on S3 in a bucket like :
/YYYY-MM/YYYY-MM-DD/<unique_id_of_mail>

Before, we used to store all this emails in a DynamoDB . We want to migrate this items to the new (MySQL & S3) setup. What's the fastest way to migrate these 21 million DynamoDB items to the new setup (MySQL & S3). For each mail stored as DynamoDB item, we have to create a MySQL record (unique_id_mail, address, subject, timestamp, ...) and a file (containing the mailbody) in S3. After one item is moved, we need to delete the DynamoDB item.

I have already tried with SDK for PHP but that would take months to complete.

Any better suggestions would be very welcome how to handle such big amount of data.

Comment: That is not a "big amount of data". Run a `Scan` against the dynamodb, retrieve each page / batch, iterate through it, create a bunch of S3 files and then run a `Insert` for the batch against the target db, then run a batch delete against dynamo, continue with the next page / batch. Yes, this will take a bit to complete but only hours, not months. If you combine the `Scan` with a `FilterExpression` you can parallelize the entire process

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Would you suggest to run this on our own server using PHP or are the better alternatives? Using PHP, it took 20 sec to complete 100 records. However, i did not try a batch Insert to the targetDB, maybe this would help already.